# PHP - Check duplicated array

Tags: php

I have for example one array:

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9
```

Now this array gets sorted into three arrays (randomly)
For example:

```
1,2,3  
4,5,6  
7,8,9
```

Now I have to create 3 arrays again with the same numbers (1-9)
But the new arrays should not include any same numbers as in the past array;

`1,3,5` (incorrect, 3 has already been with 1)

`1,5,7` (correct, all numbers are new to eachother)

Now I found a way to detect this using loops, below you see a part of the code.
`$temp_plr` are the new random created numbers (3 numbered array).
`$team_check` is on of the previous 3 numbered arrays.
This check gets executed untill it found a new combination that didnt show up before.
It works, but it is really slow sometimes, which makes the browser time-out or it just loops forever.
If you need more explanation please tell me.

```
if((in_array($temp_plr[0], $team_check) && in_array($temp_plr[1],$team_check))
    || (in_array($temp_plr[0],$team_check) && in_array( $temp_plr[2],$team_check))
    || (in_array($temp_plr[1],$team_check) && in_array( $temp_plr[2],$team_check))
) {
    $okey = false;
}
```

`$temp_plr` includes 3 values and `$team_check` also includes 3 values.
image of the end result I have made with this code:
http://i57.tinypic.com/9hqv4w.png
Like you see, alle numbers in each 3 numbered team are different from eachother in each round.

Comment: Are you trying to generate all possible variations? Like all Combinations that fit your Rules? And the Rules are three Numbers, Never a set where two numbers already have been together in one set right?

Comment: Yes basicly that is it, but there is one default array, that will be separated into sets for 3 or more times, and each time it has to look back at the previous made sets if the combination is unique.

Comment: Is that array always a set of numbers? Is the length of the array always 9 and thus the set always containing of 3 set with each 3 numbers?

Comment: no, this is a simple exmampe, in reality it can be over 48 numbers seprated in 3 arrays which contains 16 arrays which cotains a set of 2 or 3 numbers for example (like the image).
It is not necessary needed that it gets randomly created

Comment: |Okay, I have fixed this issue on a simple way.
It seems sometimes if php creates the first random numbers wrongly it ends up in a endless loop, and sometimes it creates the numbers correctly and it takes only like 50 loops.
So now I just run the script again if it made more then 100 loops, which means that it went wrong, and then it runs good sometime, which don't takes long.

Comment: Taht doesn't sound right :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to look at it differently.

Get your first trio of arrays as you are doing already.

Then, instead of just generating a new trio and seeing if it fits the rules, *make* it fit the rules.

To do this, build your new trio by picking one number from the first row of the old trio, then one from the second row, then one from the third.

For instance, if your first trio is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You can generate a new trio by picking a random number from each row:

```
1 5 9
2 4 7
3 6 8
```

This is guaranteed to fit the rule, and is capable of generating all such results from any given "old trio".

Comment: But this does not ensure that there are no two new equal trios right? Also it does not cover all possible trios :(

Comment: Yes, but is this also possible if im using like 48 numbers, and I need to generate more then 2 duplicates, because I need to sort 48 numbers into three arrays that have 16 teams and each teams includes 3 users, now those 3 users have to be unique in each three arrays, it is kind of hard to explain, I will upload a image at the main post.